# What types of wood and leaves in Southern Ontario Canada can my Rabbit eat?

Tags: diet

I have a two and a half male free roam in our home rabbit named Rusty.
Our pets stores offer limited types of tree sticks to chew to keep his teeth work down.
What other kinds of wood can I collect that are not poisonous and or unhealthy for him to chew on ?